# Object creation without vairable assignment

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

What happens to an object that is created but not assigned to a variable?  Is it garbage collected immediately?

In one of my programs, I'm testing if creating a particular object throws an exception.  In the catch block I'm returning false to the function call if an exception is thrown (I know this isn't the best way to do it).

But in either case if I do this:

```
new Object();
```

What is happening in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the object's constructor. If it stores it's own reference in another object, it won't be destroyed, of course. Otherwise it is destroyed when GC collects the next time.

Comment: I suppose this is what happens when the object creates another thread for example

Comment: Another example is an `Observable` that registers an `Observer` in the constructor and passes `this`. Which is (sadly) widely used in UI programming.

Comment: @thobens I was actually wondering how you could monitor this.

Comment: I don't know if you could uniquely identify such behavior, but a unusually fast growing heap size may be a sign. But that is just a guess, would be worth it to try out.

Answer (score 1):

Such object has no references pointing on it, so it become available for garbage collection and will be destroyed at next GC.

Comment: So it is given a random memory address with no way of accessing it outside of GC?

Comment: @Inquisitor without reference - yes, no way to access it.

Comment: @inquisitor: The GC will NOT access the object either. If there are no references, the object doesn't get touched at all, just its memory gets overwritten someday, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Generational_GC_.28ephemeral_GC.29.

Answer (score 0):

The object will be eligible for GC when the control goes out of the scope(method or block) where it is declared.

Comment: It actually can be available for GC immediately, since it's not being referenced anywhere. That's the key: it being referenced. *Scope* is involved because it affects when something is no longer referenced.